# Calling a Rcpp function from another Rcpp function while building an R package

Tags: r, function, include, package, rcpp

I took this example from a different question. I am building an R package with Rcpp. I have a function like `fun1` (below) that I want to put into its own `.cpp` file.  Then I want to call `fun1` with other functions (like `fun()` does below).  I want `fun1` in a separate file because I am going to call it from several Rcpp functions that are in different `.cpp` files. Are there certain include statements and things I need to do to make the `fun1` function accessible in the `.cpp` where `fun()` is located? Thank you.

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
a = 1:10
cpp.fun = cxxfunction(signature(data1="numeric"), 
                  plugin="Rcpp",
                  body="
int fun1( int a1)
{int b1 = a1;
 b1 = b1*b1;
 return(b1);
}

NumericVector fun_data  = data1;
int n = data1.size();
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
}
return(fun_data);
                           ")
```

So for my code I will have two `.cpp` files:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// I think I need something here to make fun1.cpp available?

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fun(Rcpp::NumericVector data1) 
{ 
    NumericVector fun_data  = data1;
    int n = data1.size();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
    }
    return(fun_data);
}
```

And a second `.cpp` file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fun1( int a1)
{int b1 = a1;
 b1 = b1*b1;
 return(b1);
}
```

Comment: This is really elementary use of C++ and has nothing to do with Rcpp.  Learn to use a common header file which any decent C++ (or even C) book will cover.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

The 'quick-and-dirty', solution -- include the function declaration in the file where you use it:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// declare fun1
int fun1(int a1);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fun(Rcpp::NumericVector data1) 
{ 
    NumericVector fun_data  = data1;
    int n = data1.size();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
    }
    return(fun_data);
}
```

The more robust solution: write header files that declare the functions, which can then be `#include`-ed in each file. So you might have a header file `fun1.h` in the same `src` directory:

```
#ifndef PKG_FOO1_H
#define PKG_FOO1_H

int foo(int);

#endif
```

which you could then use with something like:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "fun1.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fun(Rcpp::NumericVector data1) 
{ 
    NumericVector fun_data  = data1;
    int n = data1.size();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fun_data[i] = fun1(fun_data[i]);
    }
    return(fun_data);
}
```

As you progress, you're going to need to learn more C++ programming skills, so I recommend checking out [one of the books here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list); in particular, [Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) is a great introduction.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, this worked perfectly. Before this I did not know .h files worked with Rcpp or where to put them. I had one year of C++ courses, so much of the Rcpp documentation is still rather inaccessible. But Rcpp is amazing for MCMC.